# What are the advantages of using multidimensional arrays in a HTML form?

Tags: php, arrays, html, forms

Regarding the code below: What is the advantage of using the data[Category][county][Macon] array instead of just making the name 'county' or county[], and the value 'Macon', and how would they process the form data on the server side with each checkbox sharing the same value of 1? Also, why does each checkbox have a hidden input with the same name but with a value of 0?

Any assistance with helping this make sense would be appreciated.

```
<li>
    <div class="input checkbox">
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Category][county][Macon]" id="CategoryCountyMacon_" value="0" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Category][county][Macon]" value="1" id="CategoryCountyMacon" />
        <label for="CategoryCountyMacon">Macon</label>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input checkbox">
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Category][county][Madison]" id="CategoryCountyMadison_" value="0" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Category][county][Madison]" value="1" id="CategoryCountyMadison" />
        <label for="CategoryCountyMadison">Madison</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: the only advantage is complexity, that said I wouldn't do it for the sake of complexity alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is quite common in some frameworks. Imagine that `Category` is the table or a model, `county` is the column and `Madison` is the data for the column, or a related data in another lookup table.  Looks a little like CakePHP.

Let's say you have a form where a user can update something that has multiple related tables.  How do you intelligently and repeatably define what data is bound for what table etc...  The framework has logic in the receiving code that looks for the first level keys as the table/model and then the columns and values.

Also, checkboxes are only submitted if they are checked, so if not they won't be in the `$_POST` array.  Defining a hidden input with the same name and value of 0 before the checkbox insures that there will be a value, either 0 if not checked or 1 if checked.  It's a way of taking submitted values and using them as opposed to checking if something is present and then doing one thing or the other.

Comment: Thanks ...didn't realize checkbox values were not sent if they are not checked, but it makes sense, never really thought about it ...so that explains the hidden fields. I think it's probably CakePHP also or a similar framework because I don't think it would be a method that would be used commonly by an individual. I guess there aren't any advantages to doing it this way ...its just different.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have over complicated this a bit.

I assume you are showing the user a set of counties and they tick the ones they are interested in.

Now first thing to remember is that a checkbox is only sent back to the script if it is checked, if its not you never see it back in your script. Also what is sent back to the script is the `value="something"`

So if you are just interested in which counties were selected this is much easier to understand and process back in your script. Also I am not sure what function the hidden fields was serving, I am guessing none.

```
<li>
    <div class="input checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="counties[]" value="Macon" id="CategoryCountyMacon" />
        <label for="CategoryCountyMacon">Macon</label>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="counties[]" value="Madison" id="CategoryCountyMadison" />
        <label for="CategoryCountyMadison">Madison</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

So now if `Macon` and `Madison` are checked you will get an array called `counties` returned in the $_POST array like this.

```
counties[0] = 'Macon'
counties[1] = 'Madison'
```

So you can process it easily with a

```
foreach( $_POST['counties'] as $county ) {
    // $county will = 'Macon' on first iteration
    // $county will = 'Madison' on second iteration
}
```

Of course it may be better still to put the unique key of the counties row from the database into the value attribute i.e. `value="99` rather than the name `value="Macon"`. That depends upon what you want to do with it later and how you have designed your database.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I agree that would be a simpler approach. Was just curious if there was any advantage to doing it the other way, but it seems there really isn't

Comment: Well only if you have a Brain The Size of a Planet. I probably cannot keep track of arrays that complex, and certainly not when I come back in 6 month to do a modification.